# Redirecting from Salesforce.com to Community without additional login for internal users

Tags: single-sign-on, community, login

Within my Salesforce.com application, a user gets redirected to the SF organisation community when he opens a specific tab. So far the user needs to log in into the community once the browser tries to open the community url.

I have tried to pass the parameters within the url with the SessionId, PortalId/CommunityId and the OrgId but I still got prompted to login. I constructed the link used in the Visualforce controller like:

"https://fullsand-...-portal.cs1.force.com/.../s/secur/frontdoor.jsp?sid=...0&orgId=...&portalId=..."

Furthermore I tried SSO, but that also would not help as also the SF login screen would appear which I want to suppress. I used the following to set up SSO:

- Issuer = Salesforce.org domain
- Entity ID = Community Link
- Service Provider Initiated Request Binding = HTTP POST

When I use the SAML Validator, I get these messages:

- Unable to parse the response
- Premature end of file
- Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user

I read through all resources available on the net, but they seem not to have a direct answer to my question. So I would highly appreciate some help and support - thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not aware of a means for doing what you're asking since a community isn't a connected app.

Comment: As I focus on the community that you can set up in SF, it should be connected. For these communities, you have the option to configure Single Sign-On and authentication providers, but the latter only works for different orgs.

Comment: It's working as designed. If I'm not mistaken, only an admin can go back and forth between a community and the Org that owns that community provided a setting is enabled in Setup for that to happen. Doing what you're asking would make your org less secure. See [Modify Session Security Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=admin_sessions.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Although the outcome is not very satisfying, I appreciate your investment of time and effort.

Comment: See the revised & updated information I was able to locate that I believe provides what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial comments were not correct. They only apply to communities that have not yet been deployed. See Navigate to Your Communities in [Salesforce Help](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_overview.htm&type=0):

> You can easily switch between working in your internal organization and collaborating with customers or partners in communities. The global header is not available by default, the administrator for your organization must enable it for community members.
>
> Available in: Salesforce Classic
>
> Available in: Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

---

> **Note**
>
> Organizations who enabled Communities before Winter ‘14 see the new global header by default when they turn on Communities.

---

> [image: New global header] 
>   The menu on the left side lets you switch between communities and your internal organization.
>
> - To access communities from within your organization, click Drop-down arrow icon next to Organization Name in the drop-down and select the community you want to switch to. The drop-down shows Active communities that you’re a member of. If you have the “Create and Set Up Communities” permission, you also see Preview communities that you’re a member of.
> - To return to your internal organization, click Drop-down arrow icon next to Community Name in the drop-down and select your organization name.
>     Internal users who aren’t members of any community only see the company name. External users see the drop-down menu only if they belong to more than one active community.

---

> **Note**
>
> If an external user who is only a member of one Active community is given the URL for a Preview community, they don’t see the drop-down menu in the Preview community.

---

> You can work in more than one community at a time if you open each one in a different browser tab.
>
> Switching between your internal organization and your communities doesn’t have to disrupt your workflow. We automatically return you to the page where you were last working, so you can pick up right where you left off.

---

> **Note**
>
> If your organization is setting up My Domain but hasn’t finished deployment of the new custom domain, switching from a community to your internal organization directs you to the Salesforce login page instead. This can happen when you’ve logged in using a My Domain URL that has been registered but not yet deployed. Once your domain is deployed, selecting your organization in the drop-down directs you to the internal organization as expected.

---

> The **Your Name** menu on the right side contains links to edit contact information and log out. For internal users, it also contains a link to Help & Training and may also contain links to Setup and other tools depending on user permissions and enabled features. If your organization is using Lightning Experience, users with the appropriate permission can switch between Salesforce Classic and the new interface using the Switcher. Look for the *Switch to Lightning Experience* link in the **Your Name** menu. Communities aren’t supported in Lightning Experience, so to create, manage, or access communities from the global header, you’ll have to switch back to Salesforce Classic.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, that helps indeed! Hm, but after all that simple. However - GREAT!!!

Comment: As I now have looked into it a bit closer, there is a new question arising, and maybe you would be so kind to help here as well: 
I can navigate through the communities as suggested. But now I also want to navigate to sites. I see that my site refers to "CommunitiesLanding" as an active home page. According to the "Public Access Settings", only guest users are assigned to sites, right? How can I manage that both a standard and a guest user has access to my site, but the standard user can access the site from Salesforce.com, and the standard user can access both the site and the portal?

Comment: I believe this is covered in [Getting Started with Communities](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf). Look under providing access to non-secure content or something similar.